How to convert model from GraphDef format to .h5 file in Tensorflow 2.11.1
I am using TensorFlow v2.11.1. I would like to convert a model I saved as GraphDef (model.pb, model.pbtxt) as .h5 file to use in future training's
def load_frozen_model(pb_model_path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pb_model_path, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    return graph_def

def convert_frozen_to_h5(pb_model_path, input_tensor_names, output_tensor_names):
    graph_def = load_frozen_model(pb_model_path)
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")

        inputs = [graph.get_tensor_by_name(name) for name in input_tensor_names]
        print(inputs)
        outputs = [graph.get_tensor_by_name(name) for name in output_tensor_names]
        print(outputs)

        concrete_func = tf.function(lambda *x: outputs).get_concrete_function(*inputs)
        frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(concrete_func)
        keras_model = M.Model(inputs=frozen_func.inputs, outputs=frozen_func.outputs)

    return keras_model

def save_frozen_model_as_h5(pb_model_path, h5_output_path, input_tensor_name, output_tensor_name):
    K.clear_session()
    tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
    keras_model = convert_frozen_to_h5(pb_model_path, input_tensor_name, output_tensor_name)
    keras_model.save(h5_output_path)


# usage
save_frozen_model_as_h5(frozen_model_dir + '/model.pb', './model_build/model.h5', ['input:0'], ['output/mul:0', 'output/Softmax:0', 'output/Softmax:0'])

i already try something like this but not sure what im doing wrong
